# Redis cache cluster .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

I had a question. I wanted to store my data with Redis cluster and for example store a series of users with unique IDs like User:Id {User:3737} in the user cluster.

The problem I have is in the code that I can't figure out how to specifically get the data of all or one of the users from the User cluster.

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Due to the large number of Redis IDatabase options, I don't know which ones to use for setting or getting.

Is there a way to search the cache itself based on the properties of a serialized object?

```
public async Task Add(TEntity entity, string key)
{
    const string signature = nameof(TEntity);
    key = $"{signature}:{key}";
    var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);
    await _cache.StringSetAsync(key, serializedData);
}

public async Task<List<Cachable<TEntity>>> GetAll()
{
    const string signature = nameof(TEntity);
    var data = await _cache.StringGetAsync(signature);
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cachable<TEntity>>>(data!)!;
    return result;
}

public async Task<List<Cachable<TEntity>>> GetAll()
{
    const string signature = nameof(TEntity);
    var data = await _cache.HashGetAllAsync(signature);
    var some = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cachable<TEntity>>>(some);
    return result;
}
```

I tried both of these methods, but I don't think I will get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're storing each object of `type` as a separate string/key in redis, with the key following the pattern `{type}:{key}`, and I *think* you want to find all values in redis with that prefix i.e. `{type}:*`, to query all objects of a given `type`.

Assuming I've interpreted this correctly, then it is important to note that what you want to do isn't *directly* supported in redis, although that depends a bit on how often you need to do this.

There *is* a `SCAN` operation in redis which accepts glob wildcards (i.e. `foo*`); this *does* do what you expect, but:

1. it is a *server* command, not a *cluster* command; which means that in SE.Redis you would need to manually iterate the endpoints from the multiplexer, and issue `Keys(...)` against each node in turn (or at least one in each shard) - see https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan.html
2. it is not optimal, especially in large databases - even if you increase the page size (one of the parmeters), it could take a non-trivial time to complete

Another alternative is using a *hash* per `type`, keyed by the `key`, but: this will mean that each `type` is pegged to a single shard, impacting distribution. If you have a lot of types, this might not be a problem, but if you only have a few types, it is possible that a single node in the cluster takes *all* the data.

Comment: What you said solves my problem, of course it adds complexity to the program, which is not very important, but can you tell me more about its inefficiency? I meant to limit the data when taking it, for example, to take 100 users at a time so as not to get IO bound.
The solution that i see as code base on cursor type search

Comment: @Hamed let's say you have a large multi-purpose redis instance, with 2M+ keys; of those, 10k are your user keys; you need to `SCAN` over all the keys, so: approximately 2M/pageSize round-trips, plus all the server work, and most of the `SCAN` result pages are going to be empty, just with a "here's the next token to continue iterating" entry

Comment: Sure. Do you think problems like this can be solved with methods such as clustering? That is, placing Domain Aggregates in each cluster and, for example, being able to cluster aggregates for each Entity to lighten the scanned data. I'm more afraid of my operations being I/O bound.

I saw some code that executed the scan command like this: "User:*". But I don't think this action can help much in managing Big Data.

My experience with Big Data is limited, and I can't think of a better way to approach this.

Comment: @Hamed there are multiple ways of approaching this; one option is to maintain a "set" or "sorted set" of the keys that are notionally in the same bucket - the actual *payloads* are still string keys, so still using the full cluster, but that index is quickly iterable without scanning the entire database. This is the approach asp.net cache uses for the "tags" feature, for example (using "sorted set", with the score as the time, allowing TTL to be implemented in the index)